# connecting two keypad with arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, relay

I am pretty new to arduino.I am working on a project which requires comparison of two keypad inputs to operate a relay using arduino. I have found lot of info on connecting single keypad but none about connecting two keypad inputs.So how can i connect two keypad and a relay to arduino?Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It should be no problems as long as you can get enough digital inputs into the Arduino.  Search for the library KeyPad, it lets you define the pins that control each row and column and so you could use 2 2*2 keypads quite easily.

I think Keypad is very easy to use, but if you get stuck, just show what code you have so far and describe the problem and people will help you.